# Posting custom JSON from a text box in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json

I have a simple web form in ASP.NET.  Custom JSON is entered into the form and then posted to the server.  In reverse whatever is associated with the parent data object (which the json is attached to) is present in the text box when the page loaded.

While the initial set of JSON displays fine, posting the form back causes a validation error and the request to fail.  The requirements I have right now are to be able to enter in custom json data.  The data could be complex (trees of objects).  What would be the best approach to retaining security and validation on the form but allowing for the custom json?

Comment: We allow for custom constructs to be attached to a parent object (it's basically custom business objects that pertain to a specific customer).  The field, as of right now, shows this json representation of the objects in raw form, hence the problem.  It seems to choke on the "foo": [ { "childprop" : "data" for example.  I'd to be able to continue to post this custom data in raw json format if possible.

Comment: This is going to be a lot easier to help you with if you post your code. Also tell us where it is choking and what the error message and exception type are.

Comment: Sorry going off of memory since I don't have the exact code in front of me.  The raw json is a) pasted/written into the textbox or b) set on the server side via .Text property of the control.  The source in this case is the server's db were the data is stored in raw json as well.  The control being used to view / modify the data is simply an ASP.NET TextBox.  For data that is already present ( a GET call) the text box displays everything fine.  However, if json data is present in the text box a form post (executed via a click) causes the failure.

Comment: It then goes to a warning page.  That states that the text box failed validation and the post was intercepted to prevent a scripting attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try encoding the data on the client side using JavaSCribe before posting it to the server and then decoding it on the server. There are probably only several characters that are causing this.

Other option is to disable asp.net built in validation and validate the data somehow yourself.

In both cases I think you should have some kind of additional validation to make sure you don't catch a SQL injection.

Comment: I'm already using jQuery (they have encoding calls I believe) and saw an initial encode before post as an option.  Considering that could be bypassed by a malicious person that would still require a validation server side (which may be unavoidable at this point).

Comment: I ended up keep the validation turned on and then using jQuery to encode before I sent it.  Worked like a charm.